# undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the below code snippet:

```
   line_sub = Regexp.new(/\s+|"|\[|\]/)
   tmp = Array.new
    # reading a file
   while line = file.gets
     ... 
     tmp[0],tmp[1] = line.to_s.scan(/^.*$/).to_s.split('=')
    #remove unwanted characters
     tmp.collect! do |val|
       val.gsub(line_sub, "")
     end
    ...
   end
```

but when I run the code I get the error:

```
 undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

something seems to be wrong here:

```
tmp.collect! do |val|
 val.gsub(line_sub, "")
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way for your solution

```
tmp.collect! do |val|
  if val.present?   # or unless val.nil?
    val.gsub(line_sub, "")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Add one condition like this

```
     tmp.collect! do |val|
        if !val.nil?
           val.gsub(line_sub, "")
        end
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

It means `tmp[0]` and/or `tmp[1]` is `nil`. Your

```
line.to_s.scan(/^.*$/).to_s.split('=')
```

didn't work as intended. Better check the result of that part.

By the way, `line.to_s.scan(/^.*$/).to_s` does not make sense. If you want to work on each line of the file, do

```
file.each_line do |l|
  ...
  l ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the line you are reading is either empty, or it does not contain a `'='` character.

```
#Then, you get either
tmp[0], tmp[1] = ["only one element"]
# => tmp[1] = nil

#or
tmp[0], tmp[1] = []
# both are nil.
```

Answer (score 0):

If there should always be a value on each side of the "=" in the line, like `"foo=bar"` and not `"foo="`, then try something like this:

```
line.match(/(.+)=(.+)/ do |match|
  # do whatever you need with the match
  # if there is no match this block won't be executed
  tmp = match[1..2]
  tmp.map! do |string|
    string.gsub(/[\s"\[\]/, "")
  end
end
```